# Как ловить нажатие клавиш за пределами tkinter окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Как ловить нажатие клавиш за пределами tkinter окна?

Имеется окно tkinter, необходимо считать нажатие клавиш за его пределами.

Comment: Средствами tkinter - никак. Нужно создавать глобальные горячие клавиши, в tkinter такой возможности нет.

Comment: Любыми средствами можно

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл рабочее решение! Долго рыскал по просторам стака, нашёл эту тему, она и решила мою проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304574/how-can-a-tkinter-work-with-a-listener-together

```py
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import mouse

def onMouseClick(*args):
    print(args)

root = tk.Tk()

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick)
listener.start() # start thread

root.mainloop()

listener.stop()  # stop thread
listener.join()  # wait till thread really ends its job</code>
```